# Tic Tac Toe vs Bot game - After a sequence has been made the bot still makes a move

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tic-tac-toe

I'm creating a tictactoe game with a bot in react

Problem statement: Design a basic 1 player TicTacToe game in React.

Functionality:
● Player opens the app(site), selects his symbol (‘X’, ‘O’) and clicks on one of the 9 empty boxes.
● As expected his symbol should get filled up in that box.
● Second player is a computer, which is available at the following API
url: https://hiring-react-assignment.vercel.app/api/bot
method: POST
Request Body: [ null, "X", "O",null, "X", "O", "X", "O", null]
Response: 8 (Box number computer wants to fill)

● If a player wins the game ends with the winner and the winning sequence is highlighted.

Constraints:
● Should use only React hooks.
● There should only be Functional components, no Class components.
● Only the box where change has happened should get re rendered. All the boxes or the whole app
should not rerender on every click.

Here is the code in the file

I'm just having a small bug - when the game finishes or ends in a draw the bot should not make a move but it is making the move.

```
// There are redundancies in the code for example you use computerMove insted of isXturn becuase we only want the computer to move.
// Modularize the code more

import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import Square from "../Square/Square";
import classes from "./Board.module.css";

const winnerLogic = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6],
];

const Board = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(Array(9).fill(null));
  const [isXTurn, setIsXTurn] = useState(null);
  const [playerSymbol, setPlayerSymbol] = useState(null);
  const [winningSequence, setWinningSequence] = useState([]);
  const [isWinner, setIsWinner] = useState(null);
  const [computerMove, setComputerMove] = useState(null);

  const checkWinner = useCallback(() => {
    for (let logic of winnerLogic) {
      const [a, b, c] = logic;
      if (state[a] != null && state[a] === state[b] && state[a] === state[c]) {
        setWinningSequence([a, b, c]);
        return state[a];
      } else if (!state.includes(null)) {
        return "draw";
      }
    }
    setWinningSequence([]);
    return false;
  }, [state]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsWinner(checkWinner());
  }, [state, checkWinner]);

  const botMove = useCallback(async () => {
    if (computerMove === true) {
      const copyState = [...state];
      // const proxyUrl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
      const apiUrl = "https://hiring-react-assignment.vercel.app/api/bot";
      const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(copyState),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      
        if (
            typeof data === "number" &&
            data >= 0 &&
            data < 9 &&
            copyState[data] === null
        ) {
            copyState[data] = isXTurn ? "X" : "O";
            setState(copyState);
            if (isXTurn) {
            setPlayerSymbol("O");
            } else {
            setPlayerSymbol("X");
            }
            setIsXTurn(!isXTurn);
        }
    
      setComputerMove(false);
    }
  }, [state, computerMove]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isWinner === false){
        botMove();
    }
  }, [botMove]);

  const squareClickHandler = (index) => {
    if (state[index] != null || isWinner) {
      return;
    }
    const copyState = [...state];
    copyState[index] = isXTurn ? "X" : "O";
    if (isXTurn) {
      setPlayerSymbol("O");
    } else {
      setPlayerSymbol("X");
    }
    setState(copyState);
    setIsXTurn(!isXTurn);
    setComputerMove(true);
  };

  const handlePlayAgain = () => {
    setState(Array(9).fill(null));
    setIsXTurn(null);
    setPlayerSymbol(null);
    setWinningSequence([]);
  };

  const handleSymbolSelection = (symbol) => {
    if (symbol === "X") {
      setIsXTurn(true);
    } else {
      setIsXTurn(false);
    }

    setPlayerSymbol(symbol);
    setComputerMove(false);
  };

  const renderSymbolSelection = () => {
    return (
      <center>
        <h2>Select Your Symbol</h2>
        <button onClick={() => handleSymbolSelection("X")}>X</button>
        <button onClick={() => handleSymbolSelection("O")}>O</button>
      </center>
    );
  };

  const renderSquare = (index) => {
    const isWinningSquare = winningSequence.includes(index);
    return (
      <Square
        key={index}
        onClick={() => squareClickHandler(index)}
        value={state[index]}
        isWinningSquare={isWinningSquare}
      />
    );
  };

  const RenderBoardRow = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <div className={classes["board-row"]}>
          {renderSquare(0)}
          {renderSquare(1)}
          {renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className={classes["board-row"]}>
          {renderSquare(3)}
          {renderSquare(4)}
          {renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className={classes["board-row"]}>
          {renderSquare(6)}
          {renderSquare(7)}
          {renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes["board-container"]}>
      {!playerSymbol ? (
        renderSymbolSelection()
      ) : isWinner === "draw" ? (
        <>
          <center>
            Game Drawn <button onClick={handlePlayAgain}>Play Again</button>
          </center>
          <RenderBoardRow />
        </>
      ) : isWinner ? (
        <>
          <center>
            {isWinner} Won the Game{" "}
            <button onClick={handlePlayAgain}>Play Again</button>
          </center>
          <RenderBoardRow />
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <center>
            <h4>Player {playerSymbol} please move!</h4>
          </center>
          <RenderBoardRow />
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Board;
```